# Fullscreen On a Vue Project + NativeScript with Notch

Tags: nativescript, fullscreen

I would like to make my app Full-screen on a Vue Project under NativeScript, it sounds easy by #bradwaynemartin method, but there is a problem: my phone has a Notch and it leaves a black strip through the Notch,

how can I remove the strip and make my app totally full-screen?

OS: Android Pie 9

Comment: Which device / OS version you are testing with? Did you try on a device without notch design, did that work?

Comment: @Manoj Android 9 - on Redmi Note 8 - MIUI 11 WeeklyBeta - Actually I would like to keep NotchBar activated and make my app Fullscreen around the Notch. and it works on other Devices withOUT Notch

Answer (score 1):

Add this [property](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout) to application theme:

```xml
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```